# Getting an AD Attribute after authenticating with Worklight LDAP Login Module

Tags: active-directory, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing in Worklight 5.0.6.  The LDAP Login module is successfully authenticating against our Active Directory. Now, I need to pull a couple of attributes from AD to use within our mobile app.  I've searched the documentation and cannot find any example code of how to do this. Can anyone give me an example of how to pull an Active Directory attribute into the user object of Worklight?

Comment: If the module is only for authentication (as the name "LDAP Login" suggests) you will most likely have to find another library or framework to query ldap / AD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We submitted this question to IBM and they informed us that there was no way to retrieve attributes from AD/LDAP at this time unless you program an HTTP Adapter to call a script to retrieve the information. We were informed to submit a request for enhancement for this.